# Angular2: How to Enter in Full Screen Mode assert a full screen mode upto specific time?

Tags: angular, fullscreen

I am making an application in angular2 which needs that when I click a button system redirects to the next page which should be in full screen mode and a timer starts and user cannot exit the full screen mode.Basically I am making an online examination system where when user presses a button he redirected to a second page which should be in full screen.

Comment: This question requires more information. So kindly provide more information

Comment: When I click on a button on page 1 it is redirected to page 2 and when this happens the whole page should go full screen. Actually I am making some online examination kind of system in which when user starts the exam the browser should go full screen until he completes the exam.

Comment: Please update it in Question section. And if possible put your code as well